# Is there a way for blocking parent window to access to iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

Usually developers ask how to block an iframe from accessing its parent window. If I remember correctly, HTML5 can use a sandboxed iframe for this.

But what about the opposite case, preventing a parent window from having access to iframe's DOM and JS -- is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could load the iframe from a [different origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), e.g. if the parent page is from `https://test1.mydomain.com/`, using `https://test2.mydomain.com/` for the iframe would do.

Not sure if you can do this while serving both pages from the same domain -- trying to modify `document.domain` in the iframe didn't work for me and I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: ah it is automatically blocked to read (by parent window )    the iframe dom and iframe javascript   if the iframe origin is different from the parent origin. It is a good thing.So there is no security problem